# transitions in Beamer

Tags: beamer

Why is this code not working i.e., not giving me the transitions

```
\begin{itemize}
    \transdissolve
        \item Large number of possible parameter-value combinations
        \item Hard to find the optimal parameters
        \item Which parameters should be changed and by how much. 
        \item muliticollinearity or high correlation between parameter values
        \item Which criteria for evaluating the difference between observed and 
        simulated runoff.
\end{itemize}
```

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: you want each itwm to appear individually, not all at one, I suppose?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use some overlay specification; for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \transdissolve
    \transduration{2}
        \item Large number of possible parameter-value combinations
        \item Hard to find the optimal parameters
        \item Which parameters should be changed and by how much. 
        \item muliticollinearity or high correlation between parameter values
        \item Which criteria for evaluating the difference between observed and 
        simulated runoff.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also used `\transduration` to show each slide for 2 seconds. Make sure to use Acrobat Reader in Full Screen mode to view the resulting pdf document; other viewers might not show the transition effect.