# Transduration in Beamer: not changing frame

Tags: beamer, transition

The following MWE illustrate the problem (see [transitions in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26812/transitions-in-beamer))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \transdissolve
    \transduration{2}
        \item Large number of possible parameter-value combinations
        \item Hard to find the optimal parameters
        \item Which parameters should be changed and by how much. 
        \item muliticollinearity or high correlation between parameter values
        \item Which criteria for evaluating the difference between observed and 
        simulated runoff.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to show the animation on Frame 1, but not switching to Frame 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how many slides the `\transduration` should affect by using

```
 \transduration<1-4>{2}
```